# How to change default path for ".qgis2" folder on Windows?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.8, configuration, bat

I'm working with Windows 8 32Bit OS and QGIS 2.8.2.

The QGIS default installing path for `".qgis2"` folder is `C:\Users\image95\\.qgis2`. This directory stores several useful components like QGIS extensions, SVG images or cache.

I really want to move the location of this directory to my D: disk.

That's why I edited the qgis.bat file and I added the following line:

```
--configpath "D:\cci93\test_modify_config_path"
```

So, currently, my qgis.bat file is like that:

[image]

Unfortunately, my attempt did not seem to have the expected effect. When I restart QGIS and I install new extensions, the installation directory seems to always be `C:\Users\image95\\.qgis2`. Moreover, the extensions installed earlier are no longer available and usable.

Could you tell me the way to reliably and properly change the path of the directory `".qgis2"`?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\qgis-bin.exe --configpath "D:\cci93\config" %*
```

All on one line.

Comment: Dear Nathan, It works. I want to thank you very much. This is not a legend : you are the best ;-)

Answer (score 3):

QGIS 3.0 is different.
You can transfer settings in QGIS 3.0, see post here by @CrystallineEntity
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/293372/70706

I found:
Copying the whole profile folder you have modified and then deleting the default profile - WORKS

Replace the whole profile folder - WORKS

More info: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/295672/70706 @maskin